# Jig or template to hold a workpiece

Tags: writing, technical

Technical English for a foreigner - please correct and rephrase if you can come up with better alternatives.

> A machine in manufacturing usually is fed material or a workpiece to be processed. Sometimes, the orientation of the workpiece [synonyms?] is defined by a kind of jig into which the workpiece is inserted.

Is there a better word for *jig*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No -- *jig* is the correct technical term for any bit of tooling designed to hold a workpiece for the purpose of facilitating a specific operation. A *vise* or *clamp* is a general-purpose tool; it lacks the constraints that make a jig a jig.

A jig may incorporate a *template*, as in the case of a jig designed to hold a workpiece for routing a particular shape against a bearing or bushing guide, but the template is not a jig until the clamps, stops and handles (as may be appropriate) are added.

Comment: NB In the UK (and possibly elsewhere?) the word used is "vice" rather than "vise" :-)

Comment: @psmears - In AmEng, [**vise**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vise) is a tool, and [**vice**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vice) is wickedness.  Occasionally I run across a particularly wicked tool, of course...   All joking aside, *vice* is an accepted but unusual alternate spelling for the tool, but *vise* is unambiguously a tool.

Answer (score 2):

Within the sentence "Orientation of the workpiece is defined by a kind of jig into which the workpiece is inserted", it's likely the word *[fixture](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixture)* will serve better than *[jig](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jig)*.  As noted in the wikipedia [Fixture (tool)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixture_%28tool%29) article,

> The main purpose of a fixture is to locate and in some cases hold a workpiece during either a machining operation or some other industrial process.  A jig differs from a fixture in that it guides the tool to its correct position in addition to locating and supporting the workpiece.

The question refers to defining orientation of a workpiece; it does not refer to guiding the tool that operates upon the workpiece or guiding the workpiece against the tool.  Thus, the device in question is more precisely a fixture than a jig.

It is untrue that "jig is the correct technical term for any bit of tooling designed to hold a workpiece for the purpose of facilitating a specific operation".  Rightly, many machinists say *fixture* for devices that hold a stationary workpiece but don't guide a tool, and *jig* for devices that guide a moving tool or workpiece; others may use one term or the other for all such devices.